# How to install tomcat server in GoDaddy Platform to rum my jsp pages? Also is there any way to get a free SSL certificate for GoDaddy domain?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, ssl-certificate, vps, godaddy-api

I have bought a domain and web hosting from GoDaddy. I have added my full codes on cPanel but the JSP pages are not working. VPS option is there but it's very costly and is there any way to install Tomcat server without paying extra? Also it's showing not secure, so can I get a SSL Certificate for free from somewhere else and use it. It's my first project so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

you simply can not!.

GoDaddy is a highly expensive yet bad in customer satisfaction and has slow deployment website.
answer to your questions given.
also GoDaddy will not provide you a free SSL certificate at any day, you have to pay for it.

But for this i have a solution, for a free SSL certificate you can use this website- https://letsencrypt.org/
from there you can get yourself verified and can get a SSL certificate for free for your website.